# Jquery: create array of ids to pass as a get parameter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays

I have a list of checkboxes, like so:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="12" name="urssaf-check[]" class="urssaf-check">
<input type="checkbox" value="13" name="urssaf-check[]" class="urssaf-check">
```

I need to retrieve an array of the ids (values of the checkboxes) selected and pass it as a parameter in an url. So far I have this:

```
var items = [];
$('.urssaf-check').each(function (key, object) {
    items.push($(this).val());
});
```

Which gives me:

```
 ["12", "27", "26", "15", "28", "29", "30", "16", "14", "19", "17", "18", "20", "31", "32", "33", "21", "22", "34", "23", "24", "25"]
```

So far so good, but now I need this in an url, so that when I do $_GET['ids'] or similar in the controller that will write the content of the page I can see that same array of numbers.

What I try now is this:

```
 var array = { ids : items };
 var params = $.param( array, true );
```

And params gives me:

```
 ids=12&ids=27&ids=26&ids=15&ids=28......
```

Which in the var_dump of the get parameter will result on me only getting the id of the last item. If I manually add [] after "ids" it will work fine, but I want to know what is the proper way to do this with jQuery.

Edit: I need the url to open in a different window, I'm doing it like this:

```
 function MM_openBrWindow(theURL,winName,features) { 
        window.open(theURL,winName,features);
 }
 MM_openBrWindow($(this).attr('data-url')+'/?'+params, 'name', "scrollbars=yes,width=1000,height=720");
```

Comment: And what are you using the querystring for, hopefully not ajax or anything like that ?

Comment: Yes you need to add [] since that is a php expects. jQuery does not know that you need [] for the name when it is an array.

Comment: why don't you pass a string instead of an array.. what i meant is, use `join` to concate the array with special character in javascript and later use `explode()` in your PHP code.

Comment: Yeah, then how do you think I should solve the problem? Manually making the string of parameters with a for loop?

Comment: You have to tell us what you're using it for, and why you're not using the same name as you would on regular form submit etc. This smells a little bit like an X/Y problem.

Comment: It should be noted that if those checkboxes are in a form, all you need is `$('form').serialize()` to get what you want, but that would keep the elements name etc ?

Comment: It's a bit complicated, I need to open a separate window with information from each of those ids. This is a private website used by 2-3 people and I'm not worried about security here so I went for this approach. I will try the serialize to see if it works

Comment: Apparently serialize is not getting the values from the checkboxes? I'm using laravel and I'm only getting the hidden inputs created by the framework when I use blade for the form

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can pass the array directly when you post it to your controller, for example:

```
$.post( "controller.php", { 'urssaf-check[]': items } );
```

If you going to send it using post or get, there is no need to parse it.

Comment: For you to get votes, add: `$.post( "controller.php", $('.urssaf-check').serialize());`. Your answer might be incorrect. I didn't tested.

Comment: I need it to open in a new window (I edited my question) so a post request won't help me here. Anyway I will test this and tell if it works

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm going to be waiting a few days but so far I did this and it works for me as is. I'm still not happy though and think a better approach to the problem is needed:

```
            var params = "";
            for (var i = items.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
                if(i==1){
                    params += 'operations[]='+items[i];
                }else{
                    params += 'operations[]='+items[i]+'&';
                }

            };
```